# UI doesn't update through databinding when model is updated by service

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, binding

I can't figure out why my UI doesn't recognize when data changes in my model.

- I'm using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection to set my DataContext in the code-behind. I couldn't get the design-time in xaml because I don't have a default constructor in my viewmodel.
- I notice that the `PropertyChanged` event is always `null` when I step through the code but I cannot figure out how to fix that or if it's the primary cause of the problem.
- If I bind to the `Binary` and `Hex` properties directly through the `HexBinService` in xaml. (i.e. `{Binding HexBinService.Binary}`) then suddenly things work but I want to maintain that layer of separation.

Here is my example project layout:

Model

```
    public class HexBin : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _hex;
        public string Hex
        {
            get => _hex;
            set
            {
                _hex = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string _binary;
        public string Binary
        {
            get => _binary;
            set
            {
                _binary = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
```

Service Interface

```
    public interface IHexBinService
    {
        Task<bool> LoadDataAsync();

        string Binary { get; set; }

        string Hex { get; set; }
    }
```

Service

```
    public class HexBinService : IHexBinService, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private readonly HexBin _hexBin;
        private readonly Random _r = new();

        public HexBinService()
        {
            _hexBin = new HexBin();
        }

        public async Task<bool> LoadDataAsync()
        {
            // omit async calls, generate random nums

            Binary = _r.Next().ToString();
            Hex = _r.Next().ToString();

            // hardcode for example
            return true;
        }

        public string Binary
        {
            get => _hexBin.Binary;
            set
            {
                _hexBin.Binary = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string Hex
        {
            get => _hexBin.Hex;
            set
            {
                _hexBin.Hex = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

ViewModel

```
    {
        public IHexBinService HexBinService { get; }

        public HexBinViewModel(IHexBinService hexBinService)
        {
            HexBinService = hexBinService;
        }

        private async void LoadDataAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                _ = await HexBinService.LoadDataAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) when (ex is IOException or COMException)
            {
                // handle it
            }
        }

        public string Binary
        {
            get => HexBinService.Binary;
            set
            {
                HexBinService.Binary = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string Hex
        {
            get => HexBinService.Hex;
            set
            {
                HexBinService.Hex = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private IRelayCommand _loadDataCommandAsync;
        public IRelayCommand LoadDataCommandAsync => _loadDataCommandAsync ??= new RelayCommand(LoadDataAsync);

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

App.cs

```
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            Container = ConfigureDependencyInjection();
        }

        public IServiceProvider Container { get; }

        public static new App Current => (App)Application.Current;

        private static IServiceProvider ConfigureDependencyInjection()
        {
            ServiceCollection serviceCollection = new();

            _ = serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IHexBinService, HexBinService>();
            _ = serviceCollection.AddTransient<HexBinViewModel>();

            return serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
        }
    }
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!--Data and Heading-->
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <!--Load Button/Options-->
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--Data and Heading -->
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <!--Bin, Hex Heading-->
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!--Bin   |   Hex-->
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Binary" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Hexadecimal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Binary, Mode=TwoWay, TargetNullValue=(No Value)}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Hex, Mode=TwoWay, TargetNullValue=(No Value)}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Command="{Binding LoadDataCommandAsync}" Content="Load Data"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs (code-behind)

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = App.Current.Container.GetService(typeof(HexBinViewModel));
        }
    }
```

[screenshot of current window even after clicking button to change data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3dBB.png)

RelayCommand (I am rolling my own inspired by the WindowsCommunityToolkit. Havent had an issue with commands.)

```
    public interface IRelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        void RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    public sealed class RelayCommand : IRelayCommand
    {
        private readonly Action _execute;

        private readonly Func<bool>? _canExecute;

        public event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged;

        public RelayCommand(Action execute) : this(execute, null)
        {
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<bool>? canExecute)
        {
            _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object? parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute();
        }
   
        public void Execute(object? parameter)
        {
            _execute();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should always let your interfaces implement interfaces and the concrete implementations. `IHexBinService : INotifyPropertyChanged` and not `HexBinService : IHexBinService, INotifyPropertyChanged`. Otherwise the interface members are hidden unless you cast from the interface to the concrete type which contradicts the purpose of dependency injection. The injected instances should be assigned to private properties. Never pass around the IoC container neither should it be made available as global instance. There should be no reference to the container in your application code.

Comment: This makes e.g. testing very complicated. Changing IoC framework will be impossible too. No dependencies on the IoC container. Rather inject factories (usually a Func<T> delegate orabstract factory). In this case you should inject the data context into the MainWindow and then show the window from your App.xaml.cs. Application.Current is already static. App.Current is redundant. The service container must be private.

Comment: Two way binding on a TextBlock is pretty pointless.

Comment: The issue seems to be your property value delegation. You call LoadAsync which initializes the service. But this will never trigger a PropertyChanged on the view model. The service should return a result which you then assign to the properties of the view model.

Comment: I guess the service looks redundant because it is an example. You should not delegate the properties to the service directly. This would lead to ugly code as you would have to subscribe to PropertyChanged or some more specialized event of the service just to raise PropertyChanged on the view model. Call the service and expect a result. Either await it directly from the async method or listen to an event.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful feedback. I have a few follow up questions: If values must be set on the viewmodel to trigger property changed, doesn't that mean I can remove the PropertyChanged plumbing in the service and model? My understanding is only if I'm binding to a service property directly (which isn't good in this case), I would need to wire everything using PropertyChanged down to the model to detect changes on the model.

Comment: Got it all working. My steps: As for setting the datacontext, I used constructor injection in the MainWindow.xaml.cs e.g. `public MainWindow(HexBinViewModel viewmodel)`, then set the datacontext to `viewmodel`. Next I removed the StartupUri from App.xaml. Then in App.xaml.cs I overrided `OnStartUp()` and inside it, retrieved the Mainwindow from the IoC Container then called `show()`. But if I'm working in a uwp or newer winui 3 desktop app, the navigation scheme is different. but would the same startup principle apply?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You should consider the service as part of the model (in the MVVM context). It doesn't *need* to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` which is basically used by the WPF binding engine. I prefer to add specialized events when required, e.g. `BinaryChanged` or `HexChanged`. This improves readability. To answer your question more general: the *binding source* must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or implement the source properties as `DependencyProperty`. When a type does not serve as a binding source there is no requirement to implement this interface.

Comment: Generally the binding source of view is either another control or the view model. Also your statement *"If values must be set on the viewmodel to trigger property changed"* is not quite correct. You don't *have* to set the property on the view model to trigger the `PropertyChanged` or the binding to update the target. You basically can raise the `PropertyChanged` event anytime and anywhere you want.

Comment: Yes, same principle. You always have an entry point no matter the framework, also in UWP. This entry point is where you configure the application and IoC container. Then you have to manually show the view. In UWP it's a Page. You should always inject interfaces. So instead of injecting `HexBinViewModel` you should inject `IHexBinViewModel`. But yes, that's the basic flow to initialize the application.

Comment: So do you think my old property value delegation was causing the PropertyChanged event to be null, otherwise I won't be able to raise the event from anywhere in the app. Thanks btw for this feedback, has been most helpful

Comment: No, your old delegation caused that the PropertyChanged event on the view model was never raised, therefore the `Binding.Target` (the TextBlock) never updates. You current fix is optimal. But you could have also fixed it by calling `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.Hex))` after the call to  `HexBinService.LoadDataAsync()`. Due to the property delegation the PropertyChanged was only raised on the service. But the service was not the source of a `Binding`, therefore unknown to the binding engine.

Comment: Usually the framework will check if the `Binding.Source` implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. If so, it will cast the source instance from `object` to `INotifyPropertyChanged` and subscribe to the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event. Since in your example the view model was the source of the binding the PropertyChanged event should not be null. The PropertyChanged event on the `HexBinService` will be null as it is not the source of a Binding - it has no subscriber.